# Large loops hang in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

Suppose I want perform a simulation using the following `function`:

```
fn1 <- function(N) {
  res <- c()
  for (i in 1:N) {
    x <- rnorm(2)
    res <- c(res, x[2]-x[1])
  }
  res
}
```

For very large `N`, computation appears to hang.  Are there better ways of doing this?

(Inspired by: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-February/155591.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loops in R are notoriously slow, but here there's another issue.  It's much faster to preallocate the results vector, res, rather append to res at each iteration.

Below we can compare the speed of the above version with a version that simply starts with a vector, res, of length N and changes the ith element during the loop.

```
fn1 <- function(N) {
  res <- c()
  for (i in 1:N) {
     x <- rnorm(2)
     res <- c(res,x[2]-x[1])
  }
  res
}
fn2 <- function(N) {
  res <- rep(0,N)
  for (i in 1:N) {
     x <- rnorm(2)
     res[i] <- x[2]-x[1]
  }
  res
}
> N <- 50000
> system.time(res1 <- fn1(N))
   user  system elapsed 
  6.568   0.256   6.826 
> system.time(res2 <- fn2(N))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.452   0.004   0.496
```

Also, as [Sharpie points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169573/large-loops-hang-in-r/1169607#1169607), we can make this slightly faster by using R functions like `apply` (or its relatives, `sapply` and `lapply`).

```
fn3 <- function(N) {
  sapply( 1:N, function( i ){ x <- rnorm(2); return( x[2] - x[1] ) } )
}
> system.time(res3 <- fn3(N))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.397   0.004   0.397
```

Comment: What's wrong with the second answer in that R list thread: res <- rnorm(10^6)-rnorm(10^6)?

Comment: @ars: You are absolutely right - That gives the fastest solution (by an order of magnitude). The best advice would be 1. Use functions that naturally work on vectors (like  rnorm does); 2. Failing that, use an *apply function; 3. Failing that, use a for loop with preallocation.

Answer (score 9):

The efficiency of loops can be increased tremendously in R through the use of the apply functions which essentially process whole vectors of data at once rather than looping through them. For the loop shown above, there are two basic operations happening during each iteration:

```
# A vector of two random numbers is generated
x <- rnorm( 2 )

# The difference between those numbers is calculated
x[2] - x[1]
```

In this case the appropriate function would be `sapply()`. `sapply()` operates on a list of objects, such as the vector generated by the loop statement `1:N` and returns a vector of results:

```
sapply( 1:N, function( i ){ x <- rnorm(2); return( x[2] - x[1] ) } )
```

Note that the index value `i` is available during the function call and successively takes on the values between `1` and `N`, however it is not needed in this case.

Getting into the habit of recognizing where `apply` can be used over `for` is a very valuable skill- many R libraries for parallel computation provide plug-and-play parallelization through `apply` functions. Using `apply` can often allow access to significant performance increases on multicore systems with **zero** refactoring of code.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on my comment to chris_dubois's answer, here's some timing information:

```
> system.time(res <- rnorm(50000) - rnorm(50000))
user  system elapsed
0.06    0.00    0.06
```

Contrast this with fn3 from that same answer:

```
> system.time(res3 <- fn3(50000))
user  system elapsed
1.33    0.01    1.36
```

The first thing to notice is that my laptop is slower than chris_dubois's machine. :)

The second, and more important, point is that the vector approach, quite applicable here, is an order of magnitude faster.  (Also pointed out by Richie Cotton in a comment to the same answer).

This brings me to the final point: it is a **myth** that `apply` and its friends are much faster than `for` loops in R.  They're on the same order in most measurements I've seen.  Because they're just `for` loops behind the scenes.  See also this post:

> http://yusung.blogspot.com/2008/04/speed-issue-in-r-computing-apply-vs.html
>
> According to Professor Brian Ripley, "apply() is just a wrapper for a loop." The only advantage for using apply() is that it makes your code neater!

Exactly.  You should use `apply` if it's more *expressive*, especially if you're programming in a functional style.  Not because it's faster.

Comment: Good points.  My original intention for this question was to highlight the idea that preallocation can be a good thing.  Like you've pointed out, this particular example can be easily done with only vector operations.  It would nice to have a few other examples where people show alternatives for optimizing R code (kind of like  http://wiki.r-project.org/rwiki/doku.php?id=tips:programming:code_optim2&s=optimization).  Thoughts?

Comment: Hey, that's a good idea -- I'm woefully ignorant of that wiki.  I know I've come across a couple loop to vector optimizations by reading code written by others -- most recently looking at some code by Heagerty for constructing variograms.  I tend to assume it's common knowledge and not noteworthy for others, but it's better to err on the side of documenting it.  I'll go through my files and find something specific to add to the wiki, hopefully by this weekend.  Do you have any thoughts on how to structure it?  Should we just create a "vectorizing tips" page and break it out as necessary?

Comment: `apply` might be as fast as a for-loop, but `lapply` and (especially) `vapply` are typically faster since they are implemented in C and have optimized the calling of the function `FUN`. But this only matters when the actual time spent in `FUN` is small.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes loop is not needed. Since rnorm gives iid sample (theoretically), you will achieve the same result (sampling 
`X-Y`  where X and Y are N(0,1)) by doing:

```
res <- rnorm(N)-rnorm(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the most efficient replacement for your function would simply be:

```
fn <- function(n) rnorm(N,0,sqrt(2))
```

which is twice as fast as taking difference of iid normal variates. More generally though, if your goal is to run simple simulations, vector/array preallocation and calls to native functions speed up the process greatly.

If you want to perform monte-carlo simulations for statistical estimations (e.g., MCMC), R has a number of native packages. For general stochastic simulation, I am not aware of R packages but you may want to try Simpy (http://simpy.sourceforge.net/), which is excellent.