# Results transposed with R apply

Tags: r, apply, transpose

**Apologies, I just realised that this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521260/why-apply-returns-a-transposed-xts-matrix).**

This should be pretty basic but I do not really understand why it is happening. Can someone help? This is the simple code with the example 'data':

```
applyDirichletPrior <- function (row_vector) {
  row_vector_added <- row_vector + min (row_vector)
  row_vector_result <- row_vector_added / sum(row_vector_added)
}
data <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), nrow=2, ncol=4)
applied <- apply(data, 1, function(x) applyDirichletPrior(x))
```

The output is given as:

```
> applied
     [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  0.1 0.1428571
[2,]  0.2 0.2142857
[3,]  0.3 0.2857143
[4,]  0.4 0.3571429
```

Whereas I expect an output in the same format as the input data, like:

```
> applied
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.1000000 0.2000000 0.3000000 0.4000000
[2,] 0.1428571 0.2142857 0.2857143 0.3571429
```

Why and at what stage during **`apply`** is the transpose happening?

Comment: See also https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-January/086064.html and the discussion in http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01

Answer (score 8):

Combining the results of the individual apply steps is somewhat arbitrary. On what basis was your expectation different? The behaviour you see is how the documentation describes it:

> If each call to ‘FUN’ returns a vector of length ‘n’, then ‘apply’
>   returns an array of dimension ‘c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])’ if ‘n > 1’.

Note that you can easily perform the transpose afterwards:

```
> t(applied)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.1000000 0.2000000 0.3000000 0.4000000
[2,] 0.1428571 0.2142857 0.2857143 0.3571429
```

Comment: +1, another way would be to return a list and then call `rbind` on it. `do.call(rbind, unlist(apply(data, 1, function(x) list(applyDirichletPrior(x))), rec=FALSE))`

Comment: I was expecting the function to modify the (2*4) matrix by applying the indicated function at each row and then produce an output with the same dimensions as the input. I understand that apply does not serve this purpose.