# R: Get column name based on row values in R

Tags: r

I have a table like below, would like to crate suggestions based on row value in R.

This is what I have -

```
id  class1  class2  class3  class4
A   0.98    0.48    0.21    0.99
B   0.22    0.31    0.41    0.11
C   0.70    0.81    0.61    0.21
```

I would like to have two new columns ('sugg1', 'sugg2') that will give the column names of the two top maximum values for each row i.e. for the first row, 0.99 is the maximum value, so its corresponding column name is `class4`, and the next max value is 0.98 for which the column name is `class1`.

```
id  class1  class2  class3  class4  sugg1   sugg2
A   0.98    0.48    0.21    0.99    class4  class1
B   0.22    0.31    0.41    0.11    class3  class2
C   0.70    0.81    0.61    0.21    class2  class1
```

Comment: The max of the class columns goes to sugg1 and the second best to sugg2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to loop over the rows, `sort` the values in the rows decreasing, get the first 2 (`head(...)`), transpose the output and create two new columns in the original dataset.

```
df1[paste0("sugg", 1:2)] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) names(head(sort(-x),2))))

df1
#  id class1 class2 class3 class4  sugg1  sugg2
#1  A   0.98   0.48   0.21   0.99 class4 class1
#2  B   0.22   0.31   0.41   0.11 class3 class2
#3  C   0.70   0.81   0.61   0.21 class2 class1
```

---

This can also be done by `melt`ing into 'long' format, subset the first two rows after grouping by 'id'/`order`ing based on 'value' and then join `on` the original dataset

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.7+
df1[dcast(melt(df1, id.var = "id")[order(-value), head(variable,2) , 
       id], id ~paste0("sugg", rowid(id)), value.var = "V1"), on = "id"]
#   id class1 class2 class3 class4  sugg1  sugg2
#1:  A   0.98   0.48   0.21   0.99 class4 class1
#2:  B   0.22   0.31   0.41   0.11 class3 class2
#3:  C   0.70   0.81   0.61   0.21 class2 class1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C"), class1 = c(0.98, 0.22, 
0.7), class2 = c(0.48, 0.31, 0.81), class3 = c(0.21, 0.41, 0.61
), class4 = c(0.99, 0.11, 0.21)), .Names = c("id", "class1", 
"class2", "class3", "class4"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: short and simple.. let me try this out :)

Comment: Awesome! Because of the transposing detail :) One thinking, why `apply()` produces column wise. Is it default for it? or is it this time you wanted two values for each row?

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  Thanks for the kind words.  Yes, with `MARGIN = 1`, the row/columns gets transposed, which we transpose it back before assigning to the new columns.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  Also, you can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521260/why-apply-returns-a-transposed-xts-matrix) for the transposing problem.