# Applying a threshold in a row-wise fashion, where cutoff value is relative to sd of row

Tags: r, loops, apply, threshold

I have a matrix similar to this:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(100), 100, 50)
```

and I'd like to change all the values row by row, so that any value above its row (standard deviation) *2 will become 1, otherwise 0 (basically a threshold).

I tried something like this:

```
cutoff <- function(x){
  x[x < 2*sd(x)] <- 0
  x[x > 2*sd(x)] <- 1
  return(x)
} 

mT <- apply(m, 1, cutoff)
```

but it's giving me something different. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, you need to transpose the result as `apply` always returns a transposed result (See [Why apply() returns a transposed xts matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521260/why-apply-returns-a-transposed-xts-matrix) ).

```
mT <- t(apply(m, 1, cutoff))
```

You can also reduce the `cutoff` function to -

```
cutoff <- function(x){
  as.integer(x > 2*sd(x))
}
```

`x > 2*sd(x)` returns a logical value (`TRUE`/`FALSE`), if we convert it to integer it changes `TRUE` to 1 and `FALSE` to 0.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I still don't understand why it needs transposing?
I also don't understand how the as.integer function is working in this case

Comment: I edited my answer to include some explanations for both the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work:

```
t(apply(m, 1, function(x) +(x > 2*sd(x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`dapply`](https://rdrr.io/cran/collapse/man/dapply.html) from `collapse` without `t`ransposing and is very efficient

```
library(collapse)
dapply(m, cutoff, MARGIN = 1)
```