# A basic R function

Tags: r

In reading R for programmers I saw this function

```
oddcount <- function(x) {
  k <- 0
  for (n in x) {
    if (n %% 2 == 1) k <- k+1
  }
  return(k)
}
```

I would prefer to write it in a simpler style (i.e in lisp)

```
(defn odd-count [xs]
  (count (filter odd? xs)))
```

I see the function length is equivalent to count and I can write odd? so are there built-in map/filter/remove type functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A more R way to doing this would be to avoid the `for` loop, and use vectorization:

```
oddcount <- function(x) {
  sum(x %% 2)
}
```

The comparison between `x` and 2 outputs a vector as `x` itself is a vector. Sum than calculates the sum of the vector, where `TRUE` equals 1 and `FALSE` equals zero. In this way the function calculates the number of odd numbers in the vector.

This already leads to more simple syntax, although for non-vectorization-oriented people the `for` loop tends to be easier to read. I greatly prefer the vectorized syntax as it is much shorter. I would prefer to use a more descriptive name for `x` though, e.g. `number_vector`.

Comment: In this case it could be even shorter, you don't realy need the `==1` since `%%` will only be returning 0's and 1's.  Use `sum(x %% 2)`.  This might also be a little bit quicker since you are not generating logicals and ther converting them back to numeric.  Some may find the longer version more readable ( and if you were to expand this to looking for numbers that are or are not multiples of something other than 2 then you would need the longer version.

Answer (score 12):

In R, when you are working with vectors, people often prefer to work on the entire vector at once instead of looping through it (see, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142767/why-are-loops-slow-in-r) discussion).

In a sense, R does have "built in" filter and reduce functions: the way in which you can select subsets of a vector. They are very handy in R, and there are a few ways to go about it - I'll show you a couple, but you'll pick up more if you read about R and look at other people's code on a site like this. I would also consider looking at `?which` and `?'['`, which has more examples than I do here.

The first way is simply to select which elements you want. You can use this if you know the indices of the elements you want:

```
x <- letters[1:10]
> x
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

If we only want the first five letters, we can write:

```
x[1:5]
x[c(1,2,3,4,5)] # a more explicit version of the above
```

You can also select which elements you *don't* want by using a minus sign, for example:

```
 x[-(6:10)]
```

Another way to select elements is by using a boolean vector:

```
x <- 1:5
selection <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
x[selection]   # only the second and fourth elements will remain
```

This is important because we can create such a vector by putting a vector in a comparison function:

```
selection <- (x > 3)
> selection
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

x[selection]   # select all elements of x greater than 3
x[x > 3]       # a shorthand version of the above
```

Once again, we can select the opposite of the comparison we use (note that since it is boolean, we use `!` and not `-`):

```
x[!(x > 3)]    # select all elements less than or equal to 3
```

If you want to do vector comparisons, you should consider the `%in%` function. For example:

```
x <- letters[1:10]
> x %in% c("d", "p", "e", "f", "y")
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# Select all elements of x that are also "d", "p", "e", "f", or "y"
x[x %in% c("d", "p", "e", "f", "y")]  
# And to select everything not in that vector:
x[!(x %in% c("d", "p", "e", "f", "y"))]
```

The above are only a few examples; I would definitely recommend the documentation. I know this is a long post after you have already accepted an answer, but this sort of thing is very important and understanding it is going to save you a lot of time and pain in the future if you are new to R, so I thought I'd share a couple of ways of doing it with you.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at the [funprog](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) library, which includes `map`, `filter`, `reduce` etc.

Comment: Thanks, length(Filter(odd_p, xs)) seems to do the job, it seems I was asking the wrong question based on the last answer however :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with use `funprog`, but using standard R you can get the same shortness in code.

Comment: That's a good point, @Paul. Trying to force a language that uses one paradigm (vectorized) into another paradigm (functional) often results in needlessly verbose code.