# How to create and add new columns to a dataframe in R within a loop?

Tags: r

I want to create a new dataframe and keep adding variables in R with in a for loop. Here is a pseudo code on what I want:

```
X <- 100  
For(i in 1:X)  
{  
  #do some processing and store it a variable named "temp_var"

  temp_var[,i] <- z 
  #make it as a dataframe and keep adding the new variables until the loop completes  
}
```

After completion of the above loop the vector "temp_var"  by itself should be a dataframe containing 100 variables.

Comment: Just make this `temp_var` a `data.frame` outside the loop: `df <- data.frame(temp_var)`

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov - Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid using `for` loops as much as possible in `R`. If you know your columns before hand, `lapply` is something you want to use.

However, if this is constraint by your program, you can do something like this:

```
X <- 100
tmp_list <- list()
for (i in 1:X) {
    tmp_list[[i]] <- your_input_column
}
data <- data.frame(tmp_list)
names(data) <- paste0("col", 1:X)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am interested in knowing why for loops are not recommended in R?

Comment: @Arun There was a saying: if you have `for` loops in `R`, something must went wrong. That is obviously exaggerating, but it also conveys an idea that `for` loops should be generally avoided unless you know what you are doing. The main reason being, `for` loops will make your code run much slower. Instead, the `apply` family should be used. There is a more detailed discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142767/why-are-loops-slow-in-r.