# Is there a way to vectorize this operation using xapply in R

Tags: r, sapply, tapply

I have a vector

```
a <- c("there and", "walk and", "and see", "go there", "was i", "and see", 
"i walk", "to go", "to was")
```

and a data frame bg where

```
bg <- data.frame(term=c("there and", "walk and", "and see", "go there", "was i", "and see",
"i walk", "to go", "to was"), freq=c(1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1))
```

I need to create a vectorized version for  the following code using either sapply,tapply, or vapply or apply etc

```
 d <- NULL
 for(i in 1:length(a)){
     temp <- filter(bg,term==a[i])
     d <- rbind(d,temp)
 }
```

The need is search the bg data when `term==a[i]` and create a data frame `d`

I need a vector version as for loops are excruciatingly slow in R.

Here is the sample data

```
> bg
       term freq
1 there and    1
2  walk and    1
3   and see    2
4  go there    1
5     was i    1
6   and see    2
7    i walk    1
8     to go    1
9    to was    1
```

and

```
>d
       term freq
1 there and    1
2  walk and    1
3   and see    2
4   and see    2
5  go there    1
6     was i    1
7   and see    2
8   and see    2
9    i walk    1
10    to go    1
11   to was    1
```

Thanks

Comment: That for loop is excruciatingly slow because you are building the structure inside the loop instead of allocating the memory for the vector beforehand and then binding the vectors after the loop has ended.  Please show what you want the desired result to look like

Comment: Your initial statement about `for` loops is not totally true: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7142982/3710546

Comment: @RichardScriven - `dplyr::filter` i imagine.

Comment: @RichardScriven yes I am using dplyr filter as seen above. dplyr::filter is fast but the for loop is murder. My data frame has 300K rows and the computation is taking 'for'ever.

Comment: @Pascal I managed to vectoriize other versions and the performance improvement is almost logarithmic, I think.

Comment: `merge(data.frame(table(term=a)), bg, by="term")`

Comment: @latemail - Looks good. May need to massage the output.Let me check. Will get back to you later today.

Comment: @TinniamV.Ganesh - maybe just `merge(data.frame(term=a), bg, by="term", sort=FALSE)` going by your updated data.

Comment: Or using the devel version of `data.table` `data.table(term=a)[bg, on='term']`

Comment: @akrun - how new does data.table have to be to use that code? No go over here on 1.9.4

Comment: @thelatemail I meant the `1.9.5`.  For `1.9.4`, we have to set the key, instead of the `on`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This essentially becomes a `merge` operation, with a little twist to make sure that the row order follows the order in `a`:

```
out <- merge(bg, list(term=a, sortid=seq_along(a)), by="term")
out[order(out$sortid),]

#        term freq sortid
#7  there and    1      1
#10  walk and    1      2
#1    and see    2      3
#3    and see    2      3
#5   go there    1      4
#11     was i    1      5
#2    and see    2      6
#4    and see    2      6
#6     i walk    1      7
#8      to go    1      8
#9     to was    1      9
```

Or in `data.table` 1.9.5, with a nod to @akrun:

```
library(data.table)
out <- data.table(term=a, sortid=seq_along(a))[setDT(bg), on='term']
out[order(out$sortid)]
```

Or in `dplyr`:

```
left_join(data.frame(term=a), bg)
```

Comment: Or: `setDT(bg)[.(term=a), on="term"]`