# Why is the time complexity of this loop non-linear?

Tags: r, performance, loops, optimization, time-complexity

Why is the time complexity of this loop non-linear and why is it so slow? The loop takes `~38s for N=50k,` and `~570s for N=200k`. Is there a faster way to do this? `Rprof()` seems to indicate that writing to memory is very slow.

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(5, runif(200000)))
df[,1:3] <- round(df[,1:3])

Rprof(line.profiling = TRUE); timer <- proc.time()
x <- df; N <- nrow(df); i <- 1 
ind <- df[1:(N-1),1:3] == df[2:N,1:3]; 
rind <- which(apply(ind,1,all))
N <- length(rind)
while(i <= N)
{
    x$X4[rind[i]+1] <- x$X4[rind[i]+1] + x$X4[rind[i]]
    x$X5[rind[i]+1] <- x$X4[rind[i]+1] * x$X3[rind[i]+1]
    x$X5[rind[i]+1] <- trunc(x$X5[rind[i]+1]*10^8)/10^8
    x$X1[rind[i]] <- NA
    i <- i + 1
};x <- na.omit(x)
proc.time() - timer; Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof(lines = "show")
```

The purpose of this algorithm is to iterate over the data frame and combine adjacent rows that match on certain elements. That is, it removes one of the rows and adds some of that row's values to the other row. The resulting data frame should have n less rows, where n is the number of matching adjacent rows in the original data frame. Every time a pair of rows are combined, the index of the source data frame and new data frame get out of sync by 1, since one row is removed/omitted from the new frame, so `i` keeps track of the position on the source data frame, and `q` keeps track of the position on the new data frame.

The code above is updated thanks to @joran's comment. The performance is improved substantially to `~5.5s for N=50k` and `~88s for N=200k`. However, the time complexity is still non-linear, which I can't fathom. I need to run this at N = 1 million or more, so its still not great speed.

Comment: seems like you're writing c++, r has packages for that

Comment: @rawr heh, did you base that just on the code or my profile also? I wasn't aware of a more `R` way of doing this. Kinda counter-intuitive that a language for processing data sets would choke an something this simple. Still hoping I'm just doing it wrong, though. What about those packages?

Comment: both. definitely not the "r way" of doing this. just like doing the "r way" in c is not optimal. it might help to describe the input and desired results. or just write it in c++ and use one of the packages to compile it on the fly

Comment: Well I read the 'r way' is to use functions with internals coded in c? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7142846. Basically I have a data frame with some (~13%) adjacent rows that should be combined into a single row according to some criteria, exactly like in the example. Can you name/suggest some of the these packages?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the code. Endorsing the request for an improved natural language description of the procedure. The q counter is only incremented in the else-clause. What's it supposed to be doing? Also wouldn't the assignment from `df` to `x` in the consequent and  alternative clauses be simpler (and perhaps faster) if done as a group? `x[q , c('X1','X2','X3','X4','X5')]  <- df[ i, c('X1','X2','X3','X4','X5')]` or just `x[q ,1:5]  <- df[ i, 1:5]`. Another issue is the risk of mistakes when testing for equality of numeric values. This is mistake-prone.

Comment: @42 I added an explanation of the procedure to the question. I would never have thought of doing the assignment that way, and I will give it a try. Tbh, I couldn't guess the under-the-hood differences between that method or the two in my code. Surprised that `x[q,] <-df[q,]` wasn't faster. What type of mistakes are we talking about? not sure how I would avoid numeric comparisons here.

Comment: I think your expectations for what is "typical" data processing for the people who design and use R is off. This is very far from typical. That said, why loop over every row? You could identify adjacent duplicate rows in a vectorized manner: `ind <- df[1:(N-1),1:3] == df[2:N,1:3]; dup_row_ind <- which(apply(ind,1,all)) + 1`. Also, if your data is all numeric you might be better off with matrices, rather than data frames.

Comment: @joran: s/might be better off/would be better off/. Using a matrix instead of a data.frame reduces the runtime of the OP's example on my machine by an order of magnitude, and it scales linearly with the number of rows in the matrix (e.g. 5e4 rows takes ~1s, 5e5 rows takes ~10s). And putting the code into a function and byte-compiling it appears to cut the runtime even further (reduces it by half on my machine).

Comment: @Joran your code was helpful, thank you. I posted an edit above. Unfortunately, my data includes non-numeric types. Basically I'm just doing some cleaning on the dataset to fix some adjacent data points that should really be a single data point. If only we can vectorize the last part of the loop.

Comment: @Joshua I wish my data was all numeric so I could try your method. I will look into byte-compiling though.

Comment: How about `library(data.table);x <- setDT(df)[, r:=rleid(X1, X2, X3),][, .(X1=X1[.N], X2=X2[.N], X3=X3[.N], X4=sum(X4)), by=r][,X5:= trunc(X3*X4*10^8)/10^8,]
` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Only the `X4` column update depends on previous values, so the loop can be mostly 'vectorized' (with a little bit of optimization, avoiding addition of 1 to `rind` in each iteration) as

```
rind1 <- rind + 1L
for (i in seq_len(N))
    x$X4[rind1[i]] <- x$X4[rind1[i]] + x$X4[rind[i]]

x$X5[rind1] <- x$X4[rind1] * x$X3[rind1]
x$X5[rind1] <- trunc(x$X5[rind1] * 10^8) / 10^8
x$X1[rind] <- NA
na.omit(x)
```

`X4` is a numeric value and the update can be made more efficient by updating it as a vector rather than a column of a data.frame

```
X4 <- x$X4
for (i in seq_len(N))
    X4[rind1[i]] <- X4[rind1[i]] + X4[rind[i]]
x$X4 <- X4
```

For comparison, we have

```
f0 <- function(nrow) {
    set.seed(123)
    df <- data.frame(replicate(5, runif(nrow)))
    df[,1:3] <- round(df[,1:3])
    x <- df; N <- nrow(df); i <- 1 
    ind <- df[1:(N-1),1:3] == df[2:N,1:3]; 
    rind <- which(apply(ind,1,all))
    N <- length(rind)

    while(i <= N)
    {
        x$X4[rind[i]+1] <- x$X4[rind[i]+1] + x$X4[rind[i]]
        x$X5[rind[i]+1] <- x$X4[rind[i]+1] * x$X3[rind[i]+1]
        x$X5[rind[i]+1] <- trunc(x$X5[rind[i]+1]*10^8)/10^8
        x$X1[rind[i]] <- NA
        i <- i + 1
    }
    na.omit(x)
}

f1a <- function(nrow) {
    set.seed(123)
    df <- data.frame(replicate(5, runif(nrow)))
    df[,1:3] <- round(df[,1:3])
    x <- df; N <- nrow(df)
    ind <- df[1:(N-1),1:3] == df[2:N,1:3]; 
    rind <- which(apply(ind,1,all))  

    rind1 <- rind + 1L
    for (i in seq_along(rind))
        x$X4[rind1[i]] <- x$X4[rind1[i]] + x$X4[rind[i]]

    x$X5[rind1] <- x$X4[rind1] * x$X3[rind1]
    x$X5[rind1] <- trunc(x$X5[rind1] * 10^8) / 10^8
    x$X1[rind] <- NA
    na.omit(x)
}

f4a <- function(nrow) {
    set.seed(123)
    df <- data.frame(replicate(5, runif(nrow)))
    df[,1:3] <- round(df[,1:3])
    x <- df; N <- nrow(df) 
    ind <- df[1:(N-1),1:3] == df[2:N,1:3]; 
    rind <- which(apply(ind,1,all))

    rind1 <- rind + 1L
    X4 <- x$X4
    for (i in seq_along(rind))
        X4[rind1[i]] <- X4[rind1[i]] + X4[rind[i]]
    x$X4 <- X4

    x$X1[rind] <- NA
    x$X5[rind1] <- X4[rind1] * x$X3[rind1]
    x$X5[rind1] <- trunc(x$X5[rind1] * 10^8) / 10^8

    na.omit(x)
}
```

The results are the same

```
> identical(f0(1000), f1a(1000))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(1000), f4a(1000))
[1] TRUE
```

The speedup is substantial (using `library(microbenchmark)`)

```
> microbenchmark(f0(10000), f1a(10000), f4a(10000), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  f0(10000) 346.35906 354.37637 361.15188 363.71627 366.74944 373.88275    10
 f1a(10000) 124.71766 126.43532 127.99166 127.39257 129.51927 133.01573    10
 f4a(10000)  41.70401  42.48141  42.90487  43.00584  43.32059  43.83757    10
```

The reason for the difference can be seen when R has been compiled with memory profiling enabled --

```
> tracemem(x)
[1] "<0x39d93a8>"
> tracemem(x$X4)
[1] "<0x6586e40>"
> x$X4[1] <- 1
tracemem[0x39d93a8 -> 0x39d9410]: 
tracemem[0x6586e40 -> 0x670d870]: 
tracemem[0x39d9410 -> 0x39d9478]: 
tracemem[0x39d9478 -> 0x39d94e0]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[0x39d94e0 -> 0x39d9548]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
>
```

Each line indicates a memory copy, so updating a cell in a data frame incurs 5 copies of the outer structure or the vector itself. In contrast, a vector can be updated without any copies.

```
> tracemem(X4)
[1] "<0xdd44460>"
> X4[1] = 1
tracemem[0xdd44460 -> 0x9d26c10]: 
> X4[1] = 2
>
```

(The first assignment is expensive because it represents the duplication of the data.frame column; subsequent updates are to `X4`, only `X4` refers to the vector being updated, and the vector does not need to be duplicated).

The data.frame implementation does seem to scale non-linearly

```
> microbenchmark(f1a(100), f1a(1000), f1a(10000), f1a(100000), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq
   f1a(100)    2.372266    2.479458    2.551568    2.524818    2.640244
  f1a(1000)   10.831288   11.100009   11.210483   11.194863   11.432533
 f1a(10000)  130.011104  138.686445  139.556787  141.138329  141.522686
 f1a(1e+05) 4092.439956 4117.818817 4145.809235 4143.634663 4172.282888
         max neval
    2.727221    10
   11.581644    10
  147.993499    10
 4216.129732    10
```

The reason is apparent in the second line of the tracemem output above -- updating a row triggers a copy of the entire column. So the algorithm scales as the number of rows to update **times** the number of rows in a column, approximately quadratic.

`f4a()` appears to scale linearly

```
> microbenchmark(f4a(100), f4a(1000), f4a(10000), f4a(100000), f4a(1e6), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq
   f4a(100)    1.741458    1.756095    1.827886    1.773887    1.929943
  f4a(1000)    5.286016    5.517491    5.558091    5.569514    5.671840
 f4a(10000)   42.906895   43.025385   43.880020   43.928631   44.633684
 f4a(1e+05)  467.698285  478.919843  539.696364  552.896109  576.707913
 f4a(1e+06) 5385.029968 5521.645185 5614.960871 5573.475270 5794.307470
         max neval
    2.003700    10
    5.764022    10
   44.983002    10
  644.927832    10
 5823.868167    10
```

One could try and be clever about vectorizing the loop, but is it now necessary?

A tuned version of the data processing part of the function uses negative indexing (e.g., `-nrow(df)`) to remove rows from the data frame, `rowSums()` instead of `apply()`, and `unname()` so that subset operations don't carry around unused names:

```
g0 <- function(df) {
    ind <- df[-nrow(df), 1:3] == df[-1, 1:3]
    rind <- unname(which(rowSums(ind) == ncol(ind)))
    rind1 <- rind + 1L

    X4 <- df$X4
    for (i in seq_along(rind))
        X4[rind1[i]] <- X4[rind1[i]] + X4[rind[i]]

    df$X4 <- X4
    df$X1[rind] <- NA
    df$X5[rind1] <- trunc(df$X4[rind1] * df$X3[rind1] * 10^8) / 10^8

    na.omit(df)
}
```

Compared to the data.table solution suggested by @Khashaa

```
g1 <- function(df) {
    x <- setDT(df)[, r:=rleid(X1, X2, X3),]
    x <- x[, .(X1=X1[.N], X2=X2[.N], X3=X3[.N], X4=sum(X4), X5=X5[.N]), by=r]
    x <- x[, X5:= trunc(X3 * X4 * 10^8)/10^8]
    x
}
```

the base R version performs favorably with times

```
> n_row <- 200000
> set.seed(123)
> df <- data.frame(replicate(5, runif(n_row)))
> df[,1:3] <- round(df[,1:3])
> system.time(g0res <- g0(df))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.247   0.000   0.247 
> system.time(g1res <- g1(df))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.551   0.000   0.551
```

(The pre-tuning version in f4a takes about 760ms, so more than twice as slow).

The results from the data.table implementation are not correct

```
> head(g0res)
  X1 X2 X3        X4        X5
1  0  1  1 0.4708851 0.8631978
2  1  1  0 0.8977670 0.8311355
3  0  1  0 0.7615472 0.6002179
4  1  1  1 0.6478515 0.5616587
5  1  0  0 0.5329256 0.5805195
6  0  1  1 0.8526255 0.4913130
> head(g1res)
   r X1 X2 X3        X4        X5
1: 1  0  1  1 0.4708851 0.4708851
2: 2  1  1  0 0.8977670 0.0000000
3: 3  0  1  0 0.7615472 0.0000000
4: 4  1  1  1 0.6478515 0.6478515
5: 5  1  0  0 0.5329256 0.0000000
6: 6  0  1  1 0.8526255 0.8526255
```

and I'm not enough of a data.table wizard (barely a data.table user) to know what the correct formulation is.

Compiling (benefits exclusively from the for loop?) increases speed by about 20%

```
> g0c <- compiler::cmpfun(g0)
> microbenchmark(g0(df), g0c(df), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  g0(df)  250.0750 262.941 276.1549 276.8848 281.1966 321.3778    10
  g0c(df) 214.3132 219.940 228.0784 230.2098 235.4579 242.6636    10
```

Comment: Very nice solution, as always.

Comment: My hasty comment under the OP wasn't meant to be an exact solution :) Correct version is `x <- setDT(dt)[, r:=rleid(X1, X2, X3),][, s:=.N:1, r];x <- x[x[, .(X4=sum(X4)), by=r], on="r"][, X4 := i.X4,][shift(r)==r, X5:= trunc(X3 * X4 * 10^8) / 10^8,][which(s==1)][,`:=`(r=NULL, s=NULL, i.X4=NULL),]`

Comment: @Khashaa R complains of a syntax error at `:=(r=NULL, ...`

Comment: `:=` should be closed by backtick symbol.

Comment: Right-formatting would be `':='(r=NULL, s=NULL, i.X4=NULL),]`.

Comment: This is awesome, and very informative. So much here for a noob like me to learn about optimization in R. `f4a` got the runtime for `N=1e6` down to 3.5s on my machine, which is more than sufficient as it scales linearly. For my purposes, the question of non-linear scaling is now irrelevant, but for the sake of curiosity, do you think its worth pursuing in a new question?

Comment: @MattMunson on reflection the non-linearity is because the data frame update is approximately quadratic in the number of rows, as I now try to explain in my answer. The stuff at the top of `g0()` is also pretty easy to implement / understand, and worth while in terms of performance.

Comment: Good to know about the data frame updates; seems like a general proscription of iteratively writing to large data frames. I will have to figure out how negative indexing and names work in R. My code is now plenty optimized, and I think this answer will be my go-to reference for optimizing in R for the foreseeable future. Much respect, and thanks, Martin.

Comment: `df$X1[rind] <- NA` and `na.omit(df)` are not necessary as you know  which indices should be excluded: it is `df[-ind, ]` using negative indexing.

Comment: @ExperimenteR `ind` is a logical vector so one could negate it and subset `df[!ind,,drop=FALSE]`, except that it's the wrong length. `rind` is an integer vector and when equal to `integer(0)` (i.e., no duplicate elements) `df[-rind,,drop=FALSE]` would actually do the wrong thing (omit all rows). So implementing this would require some kind of conditional code, which adds complexity. Also the two-step NA assignment / na.omit() is not too costly performance-wise. I'll leave the original implementation, but agree it could be improved.

Answer (score 3):

Following is just a rewrite of @Martin Morgan's answer, utilizing the fast subsetting of `data.table`. It is around 3x faster than the `data.frame` approach.

```
library(data.table)
library(matrixStats) # for efficient rowAlls function

g01 <- function(df) {
  setDT(df)
  ind <- df[-nrow(df), 1:3, with=FALSE] == df[-1, 1:3, with=FALSE]
  rind <- which(rowAlls(ind)) + 1L

  X4 <- df$X4
  for (i in seq_along(rind))
    X4[rind[i]] <- X4[rind[i]] + X4[rind[i] - 1L]

  df$X4 <- X4
  df$X5[rind] <- trunc(df$X4[rind] * df$X3[rind] * 10^8) / 10^8
  df[-rind + 1L,]
}

g01c <- compiler::cmpfun(g01)

n_row <- 1e6
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(replicate(5, runif(n_row)))
df[,1:3] <- round(df[,1:3])
# data.frame
system.time(g0(df))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.14    0.00    1.14 
system.time(g0c(df))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.82    0.03    0.86 

# data.table 
system.time(g01(df))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.40    0.02    0.43 
system.time(g01c(df))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.12    0.03    0.16
```

Comment: Cool method. Is `data.table` basically like `data.frame` only much more optimized?