# Low efficiency when I loop in dataframe R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I use following code to map the month name to number and I find it's low efficiency compared to other dataframe computation without for loop.

```
Sys.time()
head(df[,4])
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$monthnum[i]<-match(tolower(as.character(df[i,4])), tolower(month.name))
}
Sys.time()
```

and I got output like this:

```
    > Sys.time()
[1] "2016-03-07 19:20:53 CST"
> dim(df)
[1] 229464      6
> head(df[,4])
[1] January January January January January January
Levels: April August December February January July June March May November October September
> for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
+   df$monthnum[i]<-match(tolower(as.character(df[i,4])), tolower(month.name))
+ }
> Sys.time()
[1] "2016-03-07 19:23:23 CST"
```

Can anyone the logic of for loop in dataframe. Any information will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822719/why-is-the-time-complexity-of-this-loop-non-linear) helps explain why looping with data frames is so inefficient. Your code is just `df$monthnum <- match(tolower(as.character(df[,4], tolower(month.name))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sapply` function.
First, create your function:

```
my_function = function(my_month){
  match(tolower(as.character(my_month)), tolower(month.name))
}
```

then use `sapply`

```
sapply(df[,4],my_function)
```

Comment: It's helpful and it only takes several seconds to finish, did the loop in dataframe increase the complexity.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get the second part of your comment. If that solved your problem you can click on the tick to choose it as answer.