# How to add a 2d matrix to a 3d array and preserve the shape of the 3d arrray?

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying add a matrix to each 'sub-matrix' of a 3d array. I'd like to do this without a loop.

```
a = array(1:24, dim = 2:4)
a[1,,]
a[2,,]

b = array(1:12, dim = 3:4)
b

c1 = a[1,,] + b
c2 = a[2,,] + b

c = apply(a, 1, function(a_){
  da_ = dim(a_)
  db = dim(b)
  message(sprintf("The dimensions of a_ are [%i x %i] and the dimensions of b are [%i x %i]", da_[1], da_[2], db[1], db[2]))
  a_ + b
})
```

In the above code, I would like `c[1,,]` to be equal to `c1`, and `c[2,,]` to be equal to `c2`.
Is this possible using the `apply` function?

PS: I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754213/efficiently-apply-on-array-and-preserve-structure) but no direct answer to the question was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `rep`:

```
d <- a + rep(b, each = dim(a)[1])
all.equal(d[1,,], c1)
# TRUE
```