# Get value of a matrix with row-index and column-index

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the value of a matrix with a vector of row indexes and column indexes like this.

```
M = matrix(rnorm(100),nrow=10,ncol=10)
set.seed(123)
row_index = sample(10) # 3  8  4  7  6  1 10  9  2  5
column_index = sample(10) # 10  5  6  9  1  7  8  4  3  2
```

Is there any way I can do something like

```
M[row_index, column_index]
```

and get the values for

```
M[3,10], M[8,5], ...
```

as a vector?

Answer (score 1):

We need a `cbind` to create a 2 column `matrix` where the first column denotes row index and second column index

```
M[cbind(row_index, column_index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I present is not the best way of doing things in R, because in most cases for [loops are slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142767/why-are-loops-slow-in-r/7142982#7142982) compared to vectorized operations. However, for the problem you can simply implement a loop to index the matrix. While there might be absolutely no reason at all to not specify any object that provide the data structure(such as a data-frame or a matrix), we can avoid it anyway using a loop construct.

```
for (i in 1:length(row_index)) {
 print(M[row_index[i], column_index[i]])
  }
```