# Subset a data.frame based on row-column combinations

Tags: r, subset

I want to subset a data.frame based on subscripts stored in another data.frame.

So for example, if I have the following data.frame:

```
 set.seed(1)
 x <- rnorm(5)
 df <- data.frame(x,x*x, x*2, x/2)

 df
           x      x...x      x...2         x.2
1 -0.6264538 0.39244438 -1.2529076 -0.31322691
2  0.1836433 0.03372487  0.3672866  0.09182166
3 -0.8356286 0.69827518 -1.6712572 -0.41781431
4  1.5952808 2.54492084  3.1905616  0.79764040
5  0.3295078 0.10857537  0.6590155  0.16475389
```

I want to subset the values of [1,3]  and [2,4]. Thus the data.frame which I want to use as keys for subsetting looks like this:

```
sub <- data.frame(row = c(1,2), col = c(3,4))

sub
  row col
1   1   3
2   2   4
```

My result should look like this:

```
c(df[1,3], df[2,4])
[1] -1.25290762  0.09182166
```

However, it should all be done within one `df[*]`

I know this is easy but I still cannot figure it out! So thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers so far! This was exactly what I was looking for. While implementing, I got a follow-up question: How does this work in data.tables? Because if I use the approach by akrun and Ronak Shah, I get an error saying `Error in `[.data.table`(mb_profit_df[[56]], cbind(mb_profit_max_pos[[56]][,  : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please report to data.table issue tracker if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657.`

Comment: Please check the edit from my post

Comment: ok this was my first thought as well! I hoped for a neater solution, but I will work with this :)

Comment: Why was akrun's post deleted?

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797095/get-value-of-a-matrix-with-row-index-and-column-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it into `matrix` and subset

```
df[as.matrix(sub)]
#[1] -1.25290762  0.09182166
```