# Replace all empty lists with 0 with lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I want to replace all the lists that are empty (numeric(0)) with the value 0 in the following list:

```
a <- list(numeric(0), 3.13887804749505, c(0.745977548064631, 15.7233179232099, 
4.32068483740438, 19.6680377065919, 9.24007013740377), numeric(0), 
    c(28.8670111833615, 1.27199935252619, 26.6173612819351, 46.8824614685704
    ), c(3.03425142063166, 3.08366863855608, 4.37959434697201, 
    4.00518501422067, 2.05826729526789, 2.29413068424335))
```

I was trying this:

```
b <- lapply(a, function(x) ifelse(length(x)==0,0,x))
```

But I get the first number from every list:

```
list(0, 3.13887804749505, 0.745977548064631, 0, 28.8670111833615, 
    3.03425142063166)
```

Is there a way to do this with apply and not with a loop?
The loop takes a very long time (the list is very large).

Comment: `lapply(a, function(x) if (length(x)==0) 0 else x)` The problem with `ifelse()` is that it returns a vector with the same length as its condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Ronak has shown a superior way for this particular problem it is still useful to see what was the problem with your `lapply()` attempt - which is using `ifelse()` incorrectly.

Here is a close alternative that does what intended:

```
lapply(a, function(x) if (length(x) == 0) 0 else x)
```

More concisely

```
lapply(a, \(x) if (length(x)) x else 0)
```

Comment: What now is the problem of the code in the question? ... see my comment to the question!

Comment: The problem broadly is using ifelse() incorrectly. You have given a more precise answer.

Comment: @jogo Thanks. Worked perfect. Also these lines work incredibly faster than a simple loop. Is there a short explanation for this?

Comment: @snoram The comment above is for you too.

Comment: @Asher I think it is a rather long explanation: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142767/why-are-loops-slow-in-r

Answer (score 5):

We can use `lengths` to get length of each element of list and then replace zero-length elements with 0.

```
a[lengths(a) == 0] <- 0

a
#[[1]]
#[1] 0

#[[2]]
#[1] 3.138878

#[[3]]
#[1]  0.7459775 15.7233179  4.3206848 19.6680377  9.2400701

#[[4]]
#[1] 0

#[[5]]
#[1] 28.867011  1.271999 26.617361 46.882461

#[[6]]
#[1] 3.034251 3.083669 4.379594 4.005185 2.058267 2.294131
```

Comment: thanks. I went with snoram's solution for detailed explanation.