# How to fix: slow loops in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm facing some trouble with this R looping. I imagine it's because R isn't so prepared to code this kind of looping.

Thank you in advance!

```
df <- data.frame("x1" = NULL)

a <- 1
j <- 1

while (a<201)
{
  for(i in 1:1156)
  {
    df[j,"x1"] <- j
    j <- j + 1
  }
  a <- a + 1
}

length(df$pontos)
df
```

Comment: add warnigs or error or output of code if any to help solve this better.

Comment: In my opinion the code is equivalent to `j <- 200*1156; df <- data.frame(x1=1:j); a <- 201; j <- j+1`

Comment: Yes, there is no error, just runs `200*1156` times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are loops slow in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142767/why-are-loops-slow-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs for me if you decrease the iterations in the inner for loop to 100. It might just be taking a while. Could the outer loop just be a for loop as well?

Comment: If the outer loop just be a for loop, how would it help? My real problem is the delay to run the code.

Answer (score 2):

There are no errors in the codes actually. If you put `print(a)` after `a <- a + 1`, you can see that the codes work but extremely slow. I think that is the reason why you *thought* the loop never ends.

Comment: Yes, there are no erros but the code is extremely slow.

Comment: @FelipeDourado You seem to create one-column data frame from 1 to 200 * 1156. As a more efficient method, you can just pass the `1:(200 * 1156)` as the argument to `data.frame`.