# for loop in R when we have LOOCV

Tags: r, performance, loops

I have two for loops in R with a data around 150000 observation. I tried apply() family functions but they were slower than for loop in my case. here is my code:
where `k=500` and `N= 150000`, `x` is location at each time `t` (for all observation) and `xm` is specific `x` with a specific coordination that I filtered here. At each time `j` we observe `xm` so we remove it from the data and fit the model with the rest of dataset. I had an if else condition here that removed it in order to make the loop faster.

It's so slow, I am so thankful for your help!

```
xs = 0:200
result= matrix(0, k,N ) 

for (j in 1: N){
for ( i in 1:k){
  a <- sum(dnorm(xs[i],xm[-j],bx))
  b <-  sum(dnorm(xs[i],x[-ind[j]],bx))
  result[i,j]<-a/b
}   
}
```

Comment: You are doing 75 million iterations. It is going to be slow in any interpreted language. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7142846/12545041) answer for example.

Comment: can you define `x`,`xs`, `xm`, `bx`,`ind` (also `k`, `N`) in you code? you have left a lot out...

Comment: `ind = which(u==1);
ms= m[ind,];
xm= x[ind];
bx     = 2;
k= length(xs)=501;
N=length(xm)=150000;
xs = 0:500;
Sm= diag(150,4,4)`

Answer (score 0):

Using dummy values `ind`, `x`, and `xm`, here is a solution that runs in about 10 seconds on my machine (>1000 times faster than the original code).

```
# start with a small N for verification
N <- 15e2L
xm <- runif(N)
x <- runif(N)
ind <- sample(N)
k <- 501L
xs <- 0:500
bx <- 2

system.time({
  # proposed solution
  a <- outer(xs, xm, function(x, y) dnorm(x, y, bx))
  b <- outer(xs, x[ind], function(x, y) dnorm(x, y, bx))
  result1 <- (rowSums(a) - a)/(rowSums(b) - b)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.08    0.02    0.10

system.time({
  # OP's solution
  result2 <- matrix(0, k, N)
  
  for (j in 1:N){
    for (i in 1:k){
      a <- sum(dnorm(xs[i], xm[-j], bx))
      b <- sum(dnorm(xs[i], x[-ind[j]], bx))
      result2[i,j] <- a/b
    }
  }
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  109.42    0.80  110.90

# check that the results are the same
all.equal(result1, result2)
#> [1] TRUE

# use a large N
N <- 15e4L
xm <- runif(N)
x <- runif(N)
ind <- sample(N)

system.time({
  a <- outer(xs, xm, function(x, y) dnorm(x, y, bx))
  b <- outer(xs, x[ind], function(x, y) dnorm(x, y, bx))
  result1 <- (rowSums(a) - a)/(rowSums(b) - b)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    8.62    1.10    9.73
```

Comment: thank you so much! not sure why I get this error when trying to run your code: Error in outer(xs, xm, function(x, y) dnorm(x, y, bx)) : 
  unused argument (function(x, y) dnorm(x, y, bx))

Comment: What version of R are you using? It works here: https://rdrr.io/snippets/

Comment: the code is running now but I guess it does not exclude the current time observation and calculates probability of all observation at each time point

Comment: Take a closer look. It performs the same calculations as your double `for` loop, as demonstrated by `all.equal(result1, result2)` returning `TRUE`. To get the incorrect result that you are describing, it would be `rowSums(a)/rowSums(b)` instead of `(rowSums(a) - a)/(rowSums(b) - b)`.

Comment: in this code {
  a <- outer(xs, xm, function(x, y) dnorm(x, y, bx))
  b <- outer(xs, x[ind], function(x, y) dnorm(x, y, bx))
  result1 <- (rowSums(a) - a)/(rowSums(b) - b)
} , when I run it the results of a and b are equal with shouldnot be.

Comment: My guess is the error is upstream of the `a`, `b` calculations. The only way for `a` to be the same as `b` is if `x[ind]` is the same as `xm`. Do you get something different with the double `for` loop?

Comment: yes I get different

Comment: Can you post the code that gave you a different result between the `outer` solution and the double `for` loop? When I run the code you posted along side my code, I always get the same result. I change `N`, `xm`, `x`, `ind`, `k`, `xs`, and `bx`.